# How to exclude user password field validation on update

Tags: laravel, validation

I need to be able to update user without having to put his password into the form. I have done a validation rule but I keep getting error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null. Otherwise the update works.

This is my controller:

```
 public function update(Requests\UserUpdateRequest  $request, $id)
{
    User::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all())->except('password');
    return redirect('backend/users')->with("message", "User was updated");
}
```

This is UserUpdateRequest:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'email|required|unique:users,email,' . $this->route('user'),
        'password' =>'sometimes|required_with:password_confirmation|confirmed'];


}
```

And this is the form I use:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error': '' }} ">
        {!! Form::label('name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name',  null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('name')}}</span>
        @endif

    </div>

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error': '' }}">
        {!! Form::label('email') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('email')}}</span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'has-error': '' }}">
        {!! Form::label('password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password',  ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('password')}}</span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? 'has-error': '' }}">
        {!! Form::label('password_confirmation') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password_confirmation',  ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
            <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('password_confirmation')}}</span>
        @endif
    </div>
```

Also here is migration for user table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?  I am on Laravel 7.5

Comment: Does the password always need to be provided on the form?

Comment: No. Only on create. Not on update.

Comment: But it's always displayed on the form for both create and update?

Comment: Yes, in case it still needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is occurring as 'password' is always set - if the inputs are left blank it has a `null` value.

A solution would be to remove this null value before the validator is run in your FormRequest.

Add the following to UserUpdateRequest:

```
/**
* Prepare the data for validation.
*
* @return void
*/

protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    if($this->password == null) {
        $this->request->remove('password');
    }
}
```

Comment: adding nullable : 'password' =>'nullable|required_with:password_confirmation|confirmed'];
still get :SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation error.

Comment: @PinPiguin try the above - sorry that took a while to work out